# How to properly feed data to ChartJS with different number of x(labels) and y(data) points

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs, data-visualization

I have a dataset that has data something like this

```
var data =[10,30,20,50,80,60,120,40,20,90,30,10];
var labels = [moment("12:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss'),moment("12:00:01", 'HH:mm:ss'),moment("12:00:02", 'HH:mm:ss'),moment("12:00:03", 'HH:mm:ss')];
```

I fed the data to chartJS like this

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Voltage Fluctuation',
         data: [10,20,30,40,50],
         borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
               unit: 'minute',
               displayFormats: {
                  hour: 'HH:mm:ss'
               }
            }
         }]
      },
   }
});
```

However, I'm only getting data for the first four points i.e for each label.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rookies/teptmnqb/)

I want the data to be distributed for all the labels, in this case one data point for every (4/12)seconds and adjust the graph accordingly.

Is there any possible way I can achieve that without hardcoding it by converting the labels to milliseconds format?

Comment: So each point need a label. You are getting just four point because you feed just four labels. You have to re-calculate your values for your needs so that the count of points are equal to the count of labels.

Comment: Yep, I adjusted the length of time to meet the size of the data for now. Would like to know an alternative if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and hardcoded the entire thing by chopping seconds into milliseconds in order to create arrays of equal length